# Question for Xenith (Eikon) Expert - Is the following data available...?

Tags: stocks, loans, banking, capital-gain, liquidity

In the ''Universe'' tab are many different options: Government and Corporate Bonds, Equities, Funds, Indices, Equity & Index Derivatives, Companies/Issuers, Commodities, FX & Money, Benchmarks & Curves and many more. I don't know how to name this page (tool) because there is no name of the tool available. In this tool are many filtering options available too and large table with columns with data. I had to list few (not all) options in the ''Universe'' dropdown menu so you will know what I'm referring to because I have no other way to define the location (field) in Xenith (Eikon). My question is the following: One of those options, in said dropdown menu, is also ''Loans'' but there are a list of companies who already got a loan. So this loan was already approved and already funded. This is what the dropdown menu option ''Loans'' is for. Almost for sure NOT all loans are listed. Only reported ones. It would be impossible to have all loans listed here. However, my question is different and it's related to entire Xenith (Eikon) and not just ''Universe'' dropdown menu: Does Xenith (Eikon) has a similar list, as complete as possible ( !!! ) with maximum quantity of data, with similar report but for the case of companies LOOKING for a loan (needing more money)? So I'm NOT asking for completed (funded) loan applications but for the list of searched loans - which enterprises are searching for it?

Comment: By "Indives", do you mean "Indexes"?  (Probably just a typo, but I'm not sure.)

Comment: i meant Indices